# Build error in android studio with Kotlin and Room

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-room

I was making an android studio app for school that requires use for room db, i wanted to try to use kotlin and now i have problem with the Room annotation and the kotlin debug

I'm simple trying to run the app for the db creations but something is wrong

Here's the build.gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "com.google.devtools.ksp"
}



android {
    namespace 'com.example.lordofthegames'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lordofthegames"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }


}
/*
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency {
            if ((requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") && (requested.name.startsWith("kotlin-stdlib"))) {
                useVersion("1.8.0")
            }
        }
    }
}*/

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation('com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0')
    implementation('androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0')
    implementation('androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3')
    implementation('androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3')

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10")

    def room_version = "2.5.0"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version")

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version")

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version")

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version")

}
```

the build.gradle(AppName)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0-RC'
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
        fragment_version = "1.3.6"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id "com.google.devtools.ksp" version "1.8.10-1.0.9" apply false

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "LordOfTheGames"
include ':app'
```

and the gradle.properties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4068m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
kapt.verbose=false
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and finaally the build error cause i really don't know what those error are

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\[...]\LordOfTheGames-MobileApp\LordOfTheGames

Configuration 'kspDebugKotlinProcessorClasspath' was resolved during configuration time.
This is a build performance and scalability issue.
See https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2298
Run with --info for a stacktrace.
Unable to decide if config caching is enabled
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.gradle.internal.buildoption.BuildOption$Value 
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.6.10) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\vanni\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-android-extensions\1.6.10\e61216589e513d39a8976573c83afc8784b4b6d\kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.10.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\vanni\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-android-extensions\1.6.10\e61216589e513d39a8976573c83afc8784b4b6d\kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.10.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: AmbiguousStringJetifierException, message: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           This is a known exception, and Jetifier won't be able to jetify this library.
           Suggestions:
            - If you believe this library doesn't need to be jetified (e.g., if it already supports AndroidX, or if it doesn't use support libraries/AndroidX at all), add android.jetifier.ignorelist = {comma-separated list of regular expressions (or simply names) of the libraries that you don't want to be jetified} to the gradle.properties file.
            - If you believe this library needs to be jetified (e.g., if it uses old support libraries and breaks your app if it isn't jetified), contact the library's authors to update this library to support AndroidX and use the supported version once it is released.
           If you need further help, please leave a comment at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140747218.

[...]
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.6.10) to match attributes {artifactType=android-jni, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\vanni\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-android-extensions\1.6.10\e61216589e513d39a8976573c83afc8784b4b6d\kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.10.jar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\vanni\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-android-extensions\1.6.10\e61216589e513d39a8976573c83afc8784b4b6d\kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.10.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: AmbiguousStringJetifierException, message: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
           This is a known exception, and Jetifier won't be able to jetify this library.
           Suggestions:
            - If you believe this library doesn't need to be jetified (e.g., if it already supports AndroidX, or if it doesn't use support libraries/AndroidX at all), add android.jetifier.ignorelist = {comma-separated list of regular expressions (or simply names) of the libraries that you don't want to be jetified} to the gradle.properties file.
            - If you believe this library needs to be jetified (e.g., if it uses old support libraries and breaks your app if it isn't jetified), contact the library's authors to update this library to support AndroidX and use the supported version once it is released.
           If you need further help, please leave a comment at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140747218.

[...]

==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 11) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

[...]

==============================================================================
```

The code is

DAO

```
package com.example.lordofthegames.Database

import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.room.*
import com.example.lordofthegames.db_entities.*
import com.example.lordofthegames.recyclerView.GameCardItem
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import java.util.*

@Dao
interface LOTGDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertAchievement(achievement: Achievement)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertCategory(category: GameCategory)

    @Insert
    fun insertComment(comments: Comments)

}
```

Database

```
package com.example.lordofthegames.Database
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import com.example.lordofthegames.db_entities.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

@Database(entities =
arrayOf(Game::class,
                    Achievement::class,
                    Categories::class,
                    Notes::class,
                    GameCategory::class,
                    Discussion::class,
                    Comments::class)
                , version = 3, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
abstract class LOTGDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: LOTGDatabase? = null

        val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): LOTGDatabase {

            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    LOTGDatabase::class.java,
                    "lotgdb"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.lordofthegames.Database

import android.app.Application
import androidx.annotation.WorkerThread
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import com.example.lordofthegames.db_entities.*
import java.util.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow


class LOTGRepository(
    private val lotgdao: LOTGDAO,
    var application: Application
    ) {
    val allGames: LiveData<List<Game>> = lotgdao.getAllGames()
    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insertGame(game: Game){
        lotgdao.insertGame(game)
    }
}
```

i thanks in advance anyone who have any slightest idea to solve this problem, cause its like 2 weeks that i'm trying to fix it

I tryied to search for the error, but nothing changed with switching from `kapt` to `ksp`, add or remove dependencies and updating projects

Comment: Is your Android Studio new? If so you need to upgrade jvmTarget to 11 version. jvmTarget = "11" in kotlin options to solve 3. Task error. 

And my idea is, you need to look at tasks error and solve them one by one. You have 3 task errors in errors code section.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is exactly same error what I faced (as I struggled with dagger2 dependencies), but if we look at logs, it show:

1. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`: `org.gradle.internal.buildoption.BuildOption$Value`
2. It does mention we are using here: `ksp` instead of `kapt`

So, I was facing same issue with getting error of `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`
when tried to do the same for dagger2 dependencies (moved from `kapt` to `ksp`)

I solved it by using the below combination of Kotlin, AGP and KSP versions, as below:

```
id("com.android.application") version **"8.1.2"** apply false
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version **"1.9.10"** apply false
id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version **"1.9.10-1.0.13"** apply false
```

see if that helps (please note: I am using Kotlin instead of groovy)

[image]

Comment: to add: 

I have these further notable differences, 
 compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "..."
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34

       ........................
      .........................

using  
JavaVersion.VERSION_17

Comment: @helvete, thanks for the editing